# Create interpreter with local Docker image in Pycharm 2022 in M1 Mac

Tags: docker, pycharm, apple-m1

I need to add interpreter in Pycharm 2022 through a local docker image.
Is there any way to do so in Pycharm Professional 2022 Apple Silicon?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the Pycharm is having issues in building a docker image through

`create interpreter -> docker -> build`

Then, try to build image using 'buildx' command (for M1 chip). Then, create a docker-compose.yml. And Finally, try to create the interpreter from that compose file.

That worked for me.